# nonstd:: non standard classes

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I am looking for people's opinions on my use of a set of non standard "standard classes". Basically I am working on a 'modern' C++ Lexical Analyser and Parser Generator duo to replace flex and GNU Bison which will work as a library and tool combination.

I have a number of non standard extensions of `std` library classes. The reason I am needing these nonstandard classes is to be able to express algorithms more succinctly and nearer the mathematical equivalents.

Here's a vector class that allows extension via `operator[]`, which also has a generic `Base` parameter, allowing the vector to be based at 1 rather than zero, for example. And I return indices as `size_t`'s rather than iterators as indexes are more useful in a traditional mathematical sense.

```
//
//  vector.h - auto sizing 'vector' class
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015-2016 Aaron Nathaniel Gray under the MIT License
//

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t Base = 0>
class vector : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    vector() : std::vector<T>() {}
    vector(const std::initializer_list<T> il) : std::vector<T>(il) {}
    ~vector() {}

    iterator last() { return end() - 1; }
    const_iterator clast() const { return end - 1; }

    size_t size() const { return std::vector<T>::size(); }
    void resize(size_t _size) { std::vector<T>::resize(_size); }
    T& operator [] (size_t index) {
        if (index + 1 - Base > size())
            resize(index + 1 - Base);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](index - Base);
    }
    const T operator [] (size_t index) const {
        if (index + 1 - Base <= size())
            return std::vector<T>::operator[](index - Base);
        else
            return T();
    }
    signed find(const T& value) {
        auto i = std::find(cbegin(), cend(), value);
        if (i != cend())
            return i - cbegin() + Base;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    size_t add(const T value = T()) {
        push_back(value);
        return size() - 1 + Base;
    }
    std::string toString() const;
};

template<typename T, size_t Base = 0>
std::string vector<T, Base>::toString() const {
    std::stringstream ss;

    for (size_t element = Base; element < size() + Base; ++element) {
        ss << (*this)[element];
        if (element < size() + Base)
            ss << ",";
        ss << std::endl;
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

I am wondering whether to use the namespace `nonstd::vector`.

I also have non-standard set, `deque`, and a very extensive `bitset` class.

Example:

```
nonstd::vector<size_t> accept;

for(auto state : states) {

    .... accept = ....

    this->accept[state->index] = accept;
}
```

Here, `state->index` may not be sequential or contiguous and maximum value not known, so `push_back` will not work.

And a find example:

```
nonstd::vector<Production*> productions;

...

size_t productionIndex = production.find(aProduction);
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  This would be a better question if it included an example showing how the class is meant to be used.  It would be preferable for that to show a usage where a `std::vector` would not work.

Comment: okay will do so

Comment: If you're building a library, then the library should have its own namespace, so you can just place your vector class inside the library's namespace. You might also consider naming it `Vector` with the capital `V` to further differentiate from `std::vector`.

Answer (score 10):

#### Standard classes and derivation

If a class does not have a virtual destructor it is not supposed to be derived from. Before we got the finally key word this was the indicator you were supposed to use before deriving from a class.

But its safe unless you start taking pointers to your class. So to make sure it is not used incorrectly you should put it in a private context (so nobody else can use it apart from your library).

#### Inheriting functions.

You don't need to copy functions if they have the same name (that's the point of inheriting).

```
size_t size() const { return std::vector<T>::size(); }
void resize(size_t _size) { std::vector<T>::resize(_size); }
```

Don't need these. You automatically inherit them.

#### Inheriting Constructors.

You can use the using clause to inherit all the constructors.

```
vector() : std::vector<T>() {}
vector(const std::initializer_list<T> il) : std::vector<T>(il) {}
~vector() {}
```

Can be replaced with:

```
using std::vector::vector;
```

#### Identifiers with leading underscore.

Don't use them.

```
void resize(size_t _size)
                   ^^^^^
```

DO you know the rules about a leading underscore. I do (you got it correct). But can you assume that all the people reading your code know (you can't and most get it wrong). So prefer not to use a leading underscore on your identifiers.

#### Operator[] is supposed to be fast

The `operator[]` is an unchecked access into the data. You use this when you know that your index is guaranteed correct. We also have a checked access `at()` which is used when you can't guarantee that your index is in range.

```
T& operator [] (size_t index) {
    if (index + 1 - Base > size())
        resize(index + 1 - Base);
    return std::vector<T>::operator[](index - Base);
}
const T operator [] (size_t index) const {
    if (index + 1 - Base <= size())
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](index - Base);
    else
        return T();
}
```

Your `operator[]` is severely restricting the performance of your code for people that know that their access is good.

```
for(int loop=0;loop < v.size(); ++loop)
{
    doStuff(v[loop]);  // Why do I need to check loop is in bounds
                       // each time? It is guaranteed to be in bounds
                       // by the context.
}
```

When people use `operator[]` they have already checked (or by context guranteed) that the index is in bounds. You should not be checking. You should provide an alternative function that checks and resizes.

#### find does not return an iterator

It seems strange that find does not return an iterator.

```
signed find(const T& value) {
    auto i = std::find(cbegin(), cend(), value);
    if (i != cend())
        return i - cbegin() + Base;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

#### What's all this pointer maths.

```
        return i - cbegin() + Base;
```

Use the standard functions.

```
    return std::distance(cbegin(), i) + Base;
```

#### Constructing a string is easy

Your `toString()` function is bad as all that work can be done using the std::string constructors (also the standard library uses `to_string()` you should follow the same convention).

```
std::string to_string() const
{
    return std::string(cbegin(), cend());
}
```

Note: this does nothing.

```
    ss << std::endl;
```

You should probably never use `std::endl`. It is actually very rare that you want to flush a stream (they flush themselves at the best times anyway being a human you will just make the code in-efficient by trying to overcompensate).

#### Namespace

You should definitely put your code into its own namespace. The name `vector` is just too common.

Sure `nonstd` seems like a fine name.

Personally I use an initial uppercase letter for all user defined types and namespaces. This allows me to quickly spot an object from type.

```
namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    class BlaBla
    {
        public:
            BlaBla(int x);
    };
    int bla(int y);
}


int main()
{
    namespace TA = ThorsAnvil;
    int data1 = 15 + TA::BlaBla(15); // I constructed an object here.
    int data2 = 16 + TA::bla(15);    // I called a function here.          
}
```

So I would call your stuff.

```
namespace NonStd
{
    template<typename T>
    class Vector { /* STUFF */};
};

template<typename T>
#if SomeNormalSituation
using Vec = NonStd::Vector<T>;
#else
using Vec = std::vector<T>;
#endif;

int main()
{
    Vec<char>   data;
}
```

#### Idea

Overall find.

> A vector class that allows extension via operator [] which also has a generic Base parameter allowing the vector to be based at 1 rather than zero for example.

Your crazy this is going to cause you so many issues. CS people are so used to their arrays being zero based that any other number is just going to cause errors.

#### Thoughts

> Basically I am working on a 'modern' C++ Lexical Analyser and Parser Generator duo to replace flex and GNU Bison

Hmm. I love flex/bison. Use them all the time. It will be hard to replace something that is already near perfection. There is a reason why nobody has tried to improve them in years (and all attempts to replace them have failed).

Comment: you should probably remove the code about `std::string(cbegin(), cend());` because that's definitely incorrect. `string`'s constructors all take ranges of *characters*, not *data values to be stringified*; and even if they took the latter, they still don't join them with comma characters. Everything else here looks good at first glance.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string Constructor number 6 It takes two iterators (like most containers).

Comment: Flex and GNU Bison are far from perfect and based on 30 year old YACC and lex. Bison is under the GPL also. And neither can be used as a library tools at runtime ;|

Comment: `And neither can be used as a library tools at runtime` When do you need to define a grammer at runtime? Are you dynamically trying to create a language?

Comment: Bison is GPL (like G++). But the parser code is under a special exception allowing the generated code (including the boilerplate copied verbatim from Bison). To be used anywhere without the viral copying. https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Conditions.html

Comment: When is age a factor? `and based on 30 year old YACC and lex`. Not relavant to the discussion unless new techniques have been introduced (What papers do newer parser/lexer generators incorporate?)

Comment: `far from perfect` sure orfect is hard to obtain. But lets be specific then. Point out a better newer one. Even Antler has fallen into obscurity.

Comment: Just to satisfy your curiosity yes I am intending on using new algorithms and dynamic runtime behaviour. I am working towards a meta language and a meta system.

Comment: Also I am intending on using the MIT License as this gets more uptake and is less restrictive than 'viral' GPL license as people can do what they want with the code without restriction.

Comment: The generated code from Bison is explicitly excluded from GPL. As such you can use the MIT license on the generated code.

Comment: `I am working towards a meta language and a meta system` Then I wait gladly to review your new system.

Comment: You should look at [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) which I believe tried to do the same thing.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I invite you to write some code using constructor number 6 of basic_string, and see what output you get! It won't be what you're expecting. (Or at least it won't be what OP's code does, which is the C++ equivalent of `','.join(str(x) for x in range)`.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: http://goo.gl/BLw0pw
 Works as expected.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Now compare that output (`"abc"`) to the output of the OP's code (`"a,b,c"`). For bonus points, try your code with `vector<int>{1,2,3}` — you'll be surprised that it doesn't produce `"123"`, let alone the OP's desired `"1,2,3"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile at all, for [many different reasons.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/E1OKkhtTosIW5R5T) For example, you try to use functions `cbegin` and `cend` that don't exist in the current context (maybe you meant `this->cbegin()` and `this->cend()`?); you refer to both `end() - 1` and `end - 1`; you try to use `std::initializer_list` without including the appropriate header; and so on and so forth.

Next time, you should fix all compilation errors *before* posting to CodeReview; you'll get better (well, more targeted) answers that way. And certainly the answerers will enjoy themselves more.

---

In general, don't inherit from `std::vector<T>` or any other container class. If you want to add functionality to a standard container, add it via standalone *algorithms*, such as those found in the standard `<algorithm>` header. The problem with inheritance is that either you have to abandon value semantics and start allocating everything on the heap and taking references to them (as Java and C# do), or else you have to abandon most of the advantages of inheritance. For example:

```
std::vector<int> transform_and_return(std::vector<int> v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());  // or whatever
    return std::move(v);
}
```

This function works with a normal vector, but with your `nonstd::vector` it's going to silently do the wrong thing, because of slicing.

```
nonstd::vector<int> x {1,2,3};
auto y = transform_and_return(x);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>, decltype(y)>);
```

---

And as Loki said above: *don't* index vectors from 1. That's incorrect, and will bite you *many* times if you try to maintain your code for a year or more. (For throwaway code, you could probably get away with it, because there's no maintainer to confuse.)

Comment: `cbegin()` and `cend()` are part of std::vector. The class here inherits from `std::vector<>` so they are available in this context. The problem is  the templitiztion. Using `this->cbegin()` is a bad idea and generally recommended against because `this->X` will cause problems of accidental shadowing of X.  Alternatives are: `std::vector<T>::cbeign()` to make it exploit. Or bringing it into local scope by doing `using std::vector<T>::cbegin;` inside the class declaration.

Comment: @LokiAstari: All correct, but my point was simply that the code as written doesn't compile (because `cbegin` and `cend` don't exist in the OP's context). Sure it's possible to *change* the code so that the *changed* code will compile; but that's cheating. Code posted to CR ought to be code that already compiles and works.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

namespace nonstd {

template<typename T, size_t BASE = 0>
class vector : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    using std::vector<T>::vector;

    using typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
    using typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;

    using std::vector<T>::begin;
    using std::vector<T>::end;
    using std::vector<T>::cbegin;
    using std::vector<T>::cend;

    iterator last() { return end() - 1; }
    const_iterator clast() const { return end - 1; }

    using std::vector<T>::size;
    using std::vector<T>::capacity;

#ifndef SHOW_REALLACATION
    using std::vector<T>::resize;
#else
    void resize(size_t _size) {
        size_t old_capacity = capacity();
        std::vector<T>::resize(_size);
        if (old_capacity != capacity())
            std::cerr << "Growing vector from " << old_capacity << " to " << capacity() << std::endl;
    }
#endif
    const T operator [] (size_t index) const {
        if (index + 1 - BASE <= size())
            return std::vector<T>::operator[](index - BASE);
        else
            return T();
    }
    signed find(const T& value) {
        auto i = std::find(cbegin(), cend(), value);
        if (i != cend())
            return std::distance(cbegin(), i) + BASE;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    size_t add(const T value = T()) {
        push_back(value);
        return size() - 1 + BASE;
    }
    std::string to_string() const;
};

} // end namespace nonstd
```

Okay I have compiling code now. The main problem was I took the code from my project which was compiled on MS Visual C++ which is far too permissive compared to Clang and GCC.

I have have modified the code to follow advice where applicable :-

- I have sorted the headers.
- extensive use of **using** now.
- I have put in a SHOW_REALLACATION conditional
- Used std::difference

Regarding the idiosyncrasies of my nonstd library thats why I have called it nonstd as it diverges from standard C++ and its restrictions which make some algorithms very unclear.

I do intend to follow the NL10 rule from the Core Guidelines https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/09/bjarne-stroustrup-announces-cpp-core-guidelines https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rl-camel hence not using CamelCase or Capitalization.

Also heres the code in wandbox :- 
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xtQoUyC3cf0fiiGl